# VNC goes to wrong IP (CentOS and Smoothwall VM)

Tags: centos, vnc, smoothwall

OK, this one is so very weird.

I have CentOS 6.3 (host) running Virtual Machine Manager and several virtual machines.  The host as the public IP xxx.xxx.xxx.209.  One of the virtual machines is running Smoothwall routing software and has the public IP address xxx.xxx.xxx.210.

Whenever I try to VNC to .209 (the host) over SSH I always get the Smoothwall virtual machine.  How is it that when I try to VNC to .209 it actually goes to .210?

Please let me know if there's any additional information I should post here to help with the diagnosis.  Thank you.

Comment: Port forwarding?  MAC address conflict?  It's going to something running routing software, so look there first and see what it's doing to the traffic destined for `.209`.

Comment: I'm using smoothwall only to be a DHCP server, it doesn't do routing for the public addresses.  The routing to get to the .209 and .210 addresses is handled by my colocation host and there's nothing customized there.  Any suggestions on how to go about finding conflicting MAC addresses?